# Failed to resolve: com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on the Sample in the below blog

https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-01-firebase-android-app-engine-tutorial.html

The projects fails to compile after adding the dependency

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
```

Other dependencies compile without any issue.

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
'compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Where am I going wrong ?

here is my module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tri.todoapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
}
```

Top-level gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The project fails to compile because version 2.3 doesn't exists. You should use 2.3.1:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
```

or the newest  2.4.0:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
```

You can find more information here:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I am actually using 2.3.1 ,

Comment: @Code_Yoga Please update your answer and add your project and application build.gradle otherwise we can't help you

Comment: Updated my question, added complete build.gradle file

Comment: Can you add also the project or top-level `build.gradle`?

Comment: Top-level build.gradle added

Comment: Please check that **Offline work** under `Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle` is uncheked

Comment: No, offline is not checked, and I am using default gradle wrapper

Comment: Can you open this url https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/firebase/firebase-client-android/2.4.0/ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92241/discussion-between-code-yoga-and-mattia).

Answer (score 3):

We are talking about Google api versions without mentioning **Google Repository** version.
The actual problem here is that your Google Repository doesn't "know" about the firebase version you all were trying to use.

I got same error while following the [official firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience)

My app-level build.gradle file looked like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My Google Repository version was 44

You can check yours in
*SDK Manager>Android SDK> SDK Tools* (tab)

Latest version is 46 (at the time of writing this)

**I updated to latest Google Repository version and the problem was solved!**

*You can update by checking "Google Repository" under SDK Tools tab and click "Apply" to update Google Repository to latest version*

If you do not wish to update your Google Repository version, you can still resolve the issue by lowering your firebase api version slighlty.
For my case, changing app-level build.gradle file to the following also fixes my problem:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

firebase version has been lowered to version 10.2.0 from 10.2.1

This works because 10.2.0 is known to Google repository ver 44.

I hope this answer will help many in future.

Answer (score 1):

There are two modules you need to add firebase to:

- The android module:  You should use the "Add Firebase" checkbox that appears in project structure that will add 2.3.1  to the android app.
- The backend module requires 2.4 to run in app engine and those steps require you to add the dependency manually.
  In that case, be sure you are adding the jvm client -- not the "android" client for app engine.
  compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'

Answer (score 1):

It happens because this version

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3'
```

**doesn't exist.**

You can use one of these:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.0'
```

Pay attention.

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.0'
```

is different from

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3'
```

You can find the [full list in maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.firebase%22%20AND%20a%3A%22firebase-client-android%22):

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I was actually using 2.3.1. I have mentioned it in the heading correctly. I have edited the description now. I have even used 2.4.0. , nothing was working in my case.

Comment: @Code_Yoga Nothing was working... what does it mean? In the topic the question is "Failed to resolve". If you have other issues, open a new question.

Comment: By 'Nothing works' I meant that neither 2.3.1 nor 2.4.0 is compiling, I get the same 'Failed to Resolve'

Answer (score 1):

using

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:+'
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem today, but with version 2.4.1. I could however not open the link l jcenter.bintray.com/com/firebase/firebase-client-android/2.4.1/ as mentioned by Mattia Maestrini.

Solution for me: Deactivate my VPN, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it was a dex limit error. Adding the Firebase SDK must have put me over the limit, to fix this i had to add **multiDexEnabled true** in the defaultConfig section of my app:build.gradle file as well as **compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'** in the dependencies

Here is my gradle

**gradle for project**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle module app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tranetech.openspace.firebasedemo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I not sure you still working with that project or not, but I also faced the same problem with you, my solution is

In your build.gradle (outside the app folder one), add

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        ////
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

and in your module build.gradle, add

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
}
```

apply plugin:

```
'com.google.gms.google-services'// <- this code
```

And the last, don't forget to download **google-services.json** put in your app folder, the path should look like \yourapplication\app, you also can refer to this link for download **google-services.json** file. [Download a configuration file](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592)

Answer (score 0):

compile is deprecated. You should use:

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```